# How to solve this textbox pattern

Tags: regex, vb.net

What will be the regular expression pattern is used for this 49-1/2 and also 50 should be accepted less than 50 numbers and 1/2 is optional some time it used but some time not but the first two digit  (50)must be used which is also between <50 and >10.?

Comment: You need to work on your grammar, and at least read back what you typed in. Use some capitals and punctuation marks. Also the topic of your post does not describe your problem.

Comment: i want to create a text box which can accept data like this  49-1/2 what will be the code .?

Comment: @Lectere Your comment is unacceptable. Even if the OP was from a country where their 1st language is English. A quick look at their profile shows they are not. Tolerance please. Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice

Comment: You comment is off topic. And my comment is acceptable, read the rules please @ https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask The third word in his post has a grammar error and is as general as can be. Everybody can start their question with 'How to solve' , and does not add anything to describe his specific problem. Nor does it contribute towards anybody with the same problem finding the solution. And that's the bigger goal of stackoverflow.

Comment: Please: 1) Use punctuation! 2) Give solid examples of what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The regex expression would be: `([1-4]\d|50)(-1\/2)?$`

You can also test it here: https://regex101.com/r/9UlEAV/2.

Comment: I don't know if this meets the OP's requirements because the question is not clear. But regardless, this will not match `10`, `11`, etc. unless it's followed by a whitespace character. Replace `(-1\/2|\s)` with `(-1\/2)?`.

Comment: Good one, newline is typically also a whitespace, so in this case it still worked. Anyway, with `(-1\/2)?` it unfortunately also matched to the `29` of `29-2/3` which should not happen. That is at least my understanding of the question.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It only works because you have multiple lines. What if you have only one line or have `11` at the last line? To prevent matching the `29` in `29-2/3`, you can add an end-of-line-assertion at the end `$`. So, `(-1\/2)?$` should do the trick.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. Thank you for the correction. I've changed it in my answer.